# When is a button "clicked"?

Tags: user-interface, mouse, conceptual

Most mouse-APIs allow one to check weather or not a mouse button was pressed or released. As an example: The Java-Swing-API also allows to check for a "click" event, that is just an additional event that get's triggered whenever a "release" event was triggered after a "press" event, though it is hard to imagine to a scenario where this does not happen.

When implementing my own UI with a common mouse API, I now wonder how to register a "click" upon a general button. I went ahead and checked various UIs used by various programs I use and I got the general feel that any button is considered "clicked" when the mouse button is released above it.

They do not require the mouse-button to be "pressed" above them before being "released". It seems the "pressed"-event only tries to catch an object to be "dragged", though most mouse-APIs have their own "dragged" event to be triggered, the "pressed" event seems to be used to select the item that should be dragged.

Then right as I write this, it seems that browsers do not allow button presses when the mouse was not "pressed" upon the button before being "released" above it.

Question 1: Do I miss something here or am I right in these observations?

As such, a "UI"-Class managing the components of any UI needs to consider:

- It's components to be drawn
- The components that are focused
- The components that have been "pressed" and are as such "dragged"

A "click" is triggered simply when the mouse button is "released" upon all components that are "focused". Or a "click" is triggered upon all components that were "pressed" and are still "focused"?

Question 2/3: Will this implementation be a good start or do I miss something? Which one is better?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Java! I am actually implementing everything in C++ using the glfw library!

Answer (score -1):

Question 1:

Pressed: event is generated when you push down the mouse button

Released: event is generated when you release the mouse button (which has been pressed down before)

Clicked: event is generated when a mouse button Pressed & Released.

Comment: That's what the documentation states and what I already said above. There is no clicked event triggered / callback called in the glfw library though. As such when is a button "Pressed & Released" or more clearly: When is it not when it is "released"? Never I guess. So why consider it?